# Removal of OEM dkms modules after upgrading DELL vostro 3583

Tags: upgrade, dkms, dell-vostro, oem

I have bought a DELL Vosro 3583 with ubuntu 18.10 installed. I promptly upgraded to 19.10. 
The upgrade went smoothly and everything was working fine till I saw that the kernel, still being used, was an old 4.15 kernel (vmlinuz-4.15.0-1073-oem).

I then upgraded the kernel manually using

-> `sudo apt-get upgrade linux-kernel-generic linux-headers-generic`

While doing this I saw there was an error:

```
Error! The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which does not match this kernel/arch. This indicates that it should not be built.  
Error! The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which does not match this kernel/arch. This indicates that it should not be built.
```

I rebooted, and everything seems to be working fine. The box is now running kernel 5.3.

I searched around a bit and found that I can list the dkms modules using:

-> `dkms status`

```
oem-ethernet-r8169-aspm-support-bionic, 3, 4.15.0-1073-oem, x86_64: installed  
oem-wifi-qualcomm-ath10k-lp1803647-4.15, 2.0, 4.15.0-1073-oem, x86_64: installed
```

I have one question: How to update these modules to the new 19.10 modules?

`lspci` gives the following:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)  
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
```

Thanks

EDIT: Response to heynnema:

Yes, after upgrade wifi is working fine. I dont use ethernet port anyway.

Adding the outputs requested. I had seen the dkms.conf files and saw the line "BUILD_EXCLUSIVE_KERNEL="^4.15.*"". However I expected that with upgrade to 19.10 the directory itself should have been upgraded to something similar to "oem-wifi-qualcomm-ath10k-lp1803647-5.3-x.x" instead of "/oem-wifi-qualcomm-ath10k-lp1803647-4.15-x.x".

$ sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network                   
       description: Ethernet interface  
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller  
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.  
       physical id: 0  
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0  
       logical name: enp2s0  
       version: 15  
       serial: 98:e7:43:0f:8d:28  
       width: 64 bits  
       clock: 33MHz  
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical  
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 multicast=yes  
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c1304000-c1304fff memory:c1300000-c1303fff  
  *-network  
       description: Wireless interface  
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter  
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros  
       physical id: 0  
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0  
       logical name: wlp3s0  
       version: 31  
       serial: 40:23:43:44:aa:61  
       width: 64 bits  
       clock: 33MHz  
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless  
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.3.0-40-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.1.47 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11  
       resources: irq:131 memory:c1000000-c11fffff
```

$ cat /usr/src/oem-wifi-qualcomm-ath10k-lp1803647-4.15-2.0/dkms.conf

```
PACKAGE_NAME="oem-wifi-qualcomm-ath10k-lp1803647-4.15"  
PACKAGE_VERSION="2.0"  
MAKE="'make' -C ./ KVER=$kernelver"  
CLEAN="'make' -C ./ clean"  
AUTOINSTALL="yes"  
REMAKE_INITRD="yes"  
BUILD_EXCLUSIVE_KERNEL="^4.15.*"  
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="ath"  
BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="./"  
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/updates"  

BUILT_MODULE_NAME[1]="ath10k_core"  
BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION[1]="ath10k/"  
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[1]="/updates"  

BUILT_MODULE_NAME[2]="ath10k_pci"  
BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION[2]="ath10k/"  
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[2]="/updates"  

BUILT_MODULE_NAME[3]="ath10k_sdio"  
BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION[3]="ath10k/"  
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[3]="/updates"  

BUILT_MODULE_NAME[4]="ath10k_usb"  
BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION[4]="ath10k/"  
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[4]="/updates"
```

$ cat /usr/src/oem-ethernet-r8169-aspm-support-bionic-3/dkms.conf

```
PACKAGE_NAME="oem-ethernet-r8169-aspm-support-bionic"  
PACKAGE_VERSION="3"  
MAKE="'make' -C ./ KVER=$kernelver"  
CLEAN="'make' -C ./ clean"  
AUTOINSTALL="yes"  
REMAKE_INITRD="yes"  
BUILD_EXCLUSIVE_KERNEL="^4.15.*"  
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="r8169"  
BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="./"  
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/updates"
```

Comment: With the newer kernel, does your ethernet and wi-fi work? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`. Also, go to `cd /usr/src` and you'll find at least two directories, of similar names that you see in `dkms status`. You'll find `dkms.conf` inside each directory. Edit your question and show me the contents of each `dkms.conf` file with `cat dkms.conf`.

Comment: Edited the post in response. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the upgrade of Ubuntu from 18.10 to 19.10, a lot of Dell OEM software fell to the wayside. The kernel and some dkms network software included.

Manually upgrading the kernel 4.15 to 5.3 solved some issues, and allowed the network devices to operate without the need for the older dkms modules.

So, the old OEM dkms drivers can be removed.

`sudo dkms remove oem-ethernet-r8169-aspm-support-bionic/3 --all`

`sudo dkms remove oem-wifi-qualcomm-ath10k-lp1803647-4.15/2.0 --all`

`dkms status` # should return nothing

Later, if the ethernet port becomes used and has issues, a different dkms driver can be tried:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms`

Comment: Thanks. If I remove these, then what drivers will be used? Does it mean that the drivers are already present in the new kernel and it will be picked automatically if this is removed? If after removing the wifi module I see there are issues with the wifi is there a way to re-install this module?

Comment: @Prateek These old dkms drivers are not being used on kernel 5.3. With the kernel upgrade, it's using the r8169 and ath10k_pci drivers, and they're working now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I got it now.

Comment: @Prateek status please...

Comment: Hi your answer was perfect. Sorry I did not know that I had to click the checkbox. Done now. Thanks again.